# How to implement Riverpod with multiplie Notifiers/Streams?

Tags: flutter, riverpod

In my current Flutter app, I have a service that provides 3 separate Streams.
It encapsulates a real time client that provides streams of connection state, and some other data:

```dart
class MyService implements Disposable {

  final StreamController<GameDataContract> _hubGameDataStreamController =
      StreamController.broadcast();

  final StreamController<String> _hubStreamController =
      StreamController.broadcast();

  final StreamController<PhraseEntryContract> _hubPhraseStreamController =
      StreamController.broadcast();

....
```

These are consumed by both Widget trees and in my ViewModels.
I now want to move over to Riverpod, but having some difficulty on how to design a service that provides these 3 distinct different Streams (or Notifiers, could also work).
It seems to me that a given class can only implement one type of data in Riverpod, i.e.:

```
class Counter extends StateNotifier<SomeDataType> {
...
...
```

How would I implement a service that provide multiple types of notifications/streams?

My encapsulated real time client will/must be a singleton object.
(It does not supply Dart streams for the real time events)

Comment: You can have 1 state notifier per stream and encapsulate them in your service so the stream controllers will be replaced by 3 state notifiers. Or if suits well, you can have a composite state containing GameDataContract, String and PhraseEntryContract with 1 state notifier. which will notify everytime one of the 3 properties change?

Comment: @UmairM 1) How can I create a class that encapsulates 3 state notifiers? I have really tried to find an example of that, but I haven't been successful with finding any example using Riverpod. Do you have a sample/example? 2) That seems to be a bit heavy-handed. With that design, all Widgets has to "subscribe" to a big blob of composite data type of everything; connection state, data type a, data type b... etc., Then each Widget tree/ view model has to filter out what they are interested in. Seems very clunky.

Comment: I don't have a concrete example but you can have a look at [combining providers docs](https://riverpod.dev/docs/concepts/combining_providers#can-i-read-a-provider-without-listening-to-it) to get an idea on how to achieve that. The second option was just an idea hence "if suits well" ;)